# GatewayIntentBits is not defined, even though it is defined?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am making a discord bot. I have done all the steps to make the bot, but I ran into a problem. Whenever I try to run "node bot.js" in the terminal, I get the error GatewayIntentBits is not defined, even though I have it defined in the script.

```
const {Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials} = require('discord.js');
const auth = require('./auth.json')

const bot = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    ],
    partials: [Partials.Channel, Partials.Message]
})
bot.on('ready', function() {
    logger.info('Connected')
    logger.info("Logged in as: ")
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')')
})
bot.on('message', function(user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    if (message.substring(0, 1) === "!") {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ')
        const cmd = args[0]
        args = args.splice(1)
        console.log(args)
        switch(cmd) {
            case 'search': {
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'Coming soon..'
                })
            }
            break;
        }
    }
})

bot.login('nothin to see')
```

First, I was using discord.io, and then I switched to discord.js, and that did not work at all.

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: I don't know, how can I check?

Comment: Run `node --v` in the command line

Comment: I'm using version 20.0.0 of node.js, I figured out what discord.js version I'm using, its v14.